# Amazon campaigns list endpoint is giving 401 error

Tags: amazon-mws, amazon-selling-partner-api, amazon-advertising-api

I'm trying to get the campaigns list for a profile but getting 401 error while hitting the endpoint on postman. This is the endpoint mentioned in the documentation `https://advertising-api-eu.amazon.com/sp/campaigns/list`.

Documentation Link: https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/sponsored-products/3-0/openapi/prod#/Campaigns/ListSponsoredProductsCampaigns

I'm providing correct `Amazon-Advertising-API-ClientId`, `Amazon-Advertising-API-Scope` & `Authorization` in the header. On checking console logs in Postman it gives me the following error:

`No refresh token found in environment. See documentation for information on auth setup.`

Can someone please help me with this?

- I've tried adding the refresh_token in the global env as well, but that didn't help me either